SonarQube how to exclude conditions and with blocks?
I have some lines of groovy code which cannot be tested. So I need to exclude them. I have tried setting this parameter sonar.issue.ignore.block in the SonarQube UI However, it not working. I specifically have problems excluding any if conditional statements and with blocks. Even if I try excluding the entire method, it will still run the with/if statements. How can I exclude them from being scanned and calculated for code coverage?
private void myMethod(){

//BEGIN-NOSCAN
    
    with{
            
            //my code
            if(condition) {
                do this
            } else if (condition) {
                do this
            }

        }   
}// END-NOSCAN

